# Linking with 32 bit libraries

Tags: ros, library, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build a C++ ROS node that uses functionality from a proprietary library where I only have 32-bit binaries. I know from experience that ld will not link binaries of different architectures so is there any alternative for me to make it work?

If not, is it at all feasible to set up/build a 32-bit ros installation with a minimum of pain?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41880/linking-with-32-bit-libraries/) by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 971 on 2012-08-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Setting up a 32-bit ROS installation is easy if you start with a 32-bit Ubuntu installation. The 32-bit binaries will be installed automatically if you follow the [ROS installation instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know your problem very well, I have the same.

If a 64-bit system is not absolutely necessary for your use case, prefer @joq answer instead of mine!

I compile my node with the flags:

```
set_target_properties(asr_node PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32 -fPIC")
set_target_properties(asr_node PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS -m32)
```

Now the headache part begins.
As @raul.perula stated the flags alone aren't sufficient. The libraries your package depends on are also required in 32 bit. So, I deliver the required ROS libraries (and some others) in 32-bit binaries with my package. Other system side dependencies I install as rosdeps. For others that aren't installable with rosdep I perform a check in my CMakeLists.txt and for the case they aren't installed I print a `apt-get install` command to install them. (So yes my system is polluted with 32-bit crap everywhere)

Sounds dirty and in my opinion it is dirty, but I got a 32 bit node running with a 64 bit ROS and it works like a charm.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2015-01-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raul.perula](https://answers.ros.org/users/1826/raul.perula/) on 2015-01-16**:
I think that could be a solution, but yes, it is a very dirty solution. I will prefer, for instance, to download the 32-bit roscpp ROS library and to link that one.

How have you got the required ROS libraries in 32-bit binaries without compile them?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-01-16**:
You can download the .dep files from http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/
These files you open with an archive manager and get the libraries.

**Comment by [raul.perula](https://answers.ros.org/users/1826/raul.perula/) on 2015-01-16**:
Ok. A couple of new questions @BennyRe.

1.- Where do you put the .so lib file? In a "lib" folder inside the project?
2.- How do you specify in the CMakeFile.txt to link with that file?

Thanks!

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-01-19**:\

1. Yes I've got a lib folder in my package.
2. I add them to `target_link_libraries` and remove the `catkin_LIBRARIES` from there. I had to remove them because they would add the 64-bit libraries from the system.

**Comment by [khairulizwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25088/khairulizwan/) on 2016-02-01**:
how to install others 32 bit dependencies like roscpp and etc?

**Comment by [khairulizwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25088/khairulizwan/) on 2016-02-01**:
or maybe the doubt is how you do the deliver the required ROS libraries (which is 32 bit right; like roscpp and etc) ?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2016-02-01**:
I deliver the required ROS libraries (and some others) in 32-bit binaries with my package in a libs directory.

**Comment by [khairulizwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25088/khairulizwan/) on 2016-02-01**:
how did you do that, i am sorry i am newbie about linux and ros too..where did you get the file and etc...

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2016-02-02**:
Please read the above comments. I downloaded the packages from http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ and extracted the .so libs. Then I put these libs in the lib directory of my package. In the CMakeLists.txt you link against these.

**Comment by [khairulizwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25088/khairulizwan/) on 2016-02-03**:
which file i should download to get libroscpp.so?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2016-02-03**:
Assuming you are using Ubuntu 14.04 and Indigo download [this](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-roscpp/ros-indigo-roscpp_1.11.16-0trusty-20151111-0524-+0000_i386.deb) file and open it with the archive manager. This file contains libroscpp.so